# Jenkins Node/Slave(Mac iOS build) - how to get the build package

Tags: jenkins

I have setup Jenkins and everything is fine. It is connected(JNLP) and builds fine.

But how can I get the build back onto the master(the server hosting Jenkins)?

One thing could be to activate a script on the slave/node to copy the build. But since we have this very nice connected JNLP, my first thought was to get it through this connection?

Thanks in advance
Regards
christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you'd use the artifacts mechanism to save off the results of the build (the .app for example) and then in another script to retrieve them and take the next step and Jenkins takes care of storing them for you.

To save them off, add a post-build action to `Archive the artifacts` and then give the path of the artifacts you want to save (optionally excluding some elements, etc).

When I store artifacts for iPhone builds, I usually store the -dSYM.zip and .ipa files.

If you want to use them in another build step, you can then use the `Copy Artifact Plugin` to copy them as a pre-build step and then operate on them later (for example: if you want to manually release the .ipa and dSYM.zip files to TestFlightApp or HockeyApp or another distribution mechanism).